# WooCommerce duplicate product programatically, updating some properties

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to duplicate a variable product and update a handful of properties.

When I run this function, the product status is "Draft" and the stock is listed as "Out of Stock", while all of the variations have the correct Regular Price and Stock quantity and Managed stock? Is checked.

I tried setting these properties before the product is saved with woocommerce_product_duplicate_before_save, but this hook is executed several times, once for the parent product and again for each variation.

I've also tried selecting the most recently created product with WC_Product_Query.  The correct product is selected, but the properties are unchanged before and after the set methods are executed.

How can I update the properties of a duplicate variable product in WooCommerce?

```
function test_dupproduct(){
    $product = wc_get_product( '1000' );
    //woocommerce_product_duplicate_before_save
    $wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;
    $dupproduct = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( wc_get_product( $product ) );
    $dupproduct = $query->get_products();
    $dupproduct->set_sku( '99999' );
    $dupproduct->set_name( 'Product Name' );
    $dupproduct->set_short_description('Product Short Description');
    $dupproduct->set_status( 'Published' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

The following is missing:

- recall the product object, before all setter methods
- set the product slug corresponding to the product name
- set the right product status
- add the end, the magical [`WC_Product` `save()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1409) method

I have removed unnecessary:

- `wc_get_product( $product )` as argument inside product_duplicate() method
- `$dupproduct = $query->get_products();`

The working function (hooked here in `template_redirect` hook just for testing:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'test_dup_product');
function test_dup_product(){
    $product = wc_get_product( 1000 );
    $wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;

    $dup_product = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( $product );
    $dup_product = wc_get_product( $dup_product->get_id() ); // recall the WC_Product Object
    $dup_product->set_sku( '555555' );
    $dup_product->set_name( 'Product Name' );
    $dup_product->set_slug( sanitize_title('Product Name') ); // slug
    $dup_product->set_short_description('Product Short Description');
    $dup_product->set_status( 'publish' );

    $dup_product->save(); // Save
}
```

The product is now saved with all extra data with and published.

Comment: I thought this would do the trick, but the duplicate product properties remain unchanged, the product status is "Draft" and the stock is listed as "Out of Stock", while the variation properties appear to be duplicated correctly.

Comment: I discovered a typo left over from one of my edits.  I removed the line "$dupproduct = $query->get_products();", but the result is unchanged.

Comment: I changed the set_status from "Published" to "publish", and now the variable products appeared to be updating correctly.  Thanks!